# Proper way to save date input data to Firebase with simpleLogin

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebasesimplelogin

I'm new to firebase, and I'm trying to add a Date Of Birth field to a form and save it to Firebase.

The input field in the form looks like this:

```
<label for="birthdate">Date of Birth</label>
  <input type="date" id="birthdate" name="birthdate" 
  ng-model="user.birthdate" ng-required="true" placeholder="Last Name">
  <p class="error validationerror"
  ng-show="myform.birthdate.$invalid && myform.birthdate.$touched">
  Birthdate is required</p>
```

Following a lynda.com tutorial, a working register function was created like this:

```
register : function(user) {
      return simpleLogin.$createUser(user.email, user.password)
      .then(function(regUser){
        var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'users');
        var firebaseUsers = $firebase(ref);

        var userInfo = {
          date: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
          regUser: regUser.uid,
          firstname: user.firstname,
          lastname: user.lastname,
          email: user.email
        }

        firebaseUsers.$set(regUser.uid, userInfo);
      }); //add user
    }, //register
```

I tried to simply add another `birthdate: user.birthdate` **key:value** pair to the end after email: **user.email** but that didn't work.

```
register : function(user) {
      return simpleLogin.$createUser(user.email, user.password)
      .then(function(regUser){
        var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'users');
        var firebaseUsers = $firebase(ref);

        var userInfo = {
          date: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
          regUser: regUser.uid,
          firstname: user.firstname,
          lastname: user.lastname,
          email: user.email,
          birthdate: user.birthdate
        }

        firebaseUsers.$set(regUser.uid, userInfo);
      }); //add user
    }, //register
```

Nothing gets added to firebase for the birthdate.

If I do `console.log("user.birthdate: "+ user.birthdate);` right after **var userInfo** I can see the date that was chosen in the date picker... so I know its getting from the form into that register function.

I'm guessing that simpleLogin can only have firstname, lastname, and email?

Comment: Considering there is a [guide written on the topic of authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html), which includes a [section on storing user data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing), I'd recommend upgrading to a current version of the SDK, digging into those guides, and saving yourself a ton of thrashing with fundamental concepts.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I had finished a lynda.com tutorial and was trying to modify what was taught in the tutorial. I guess the tutorial is now out of date considering that Firebase Simple Login has been deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few helpful notes:

- [Firebase Simple Login](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-simple-login) has been *deprecated* by Firebase, in favor of the native authentication methods built into each of the Firebase client libraries. That said, it will continue to work.
- Both Firebase Simple Login, and the native Firebase authentication, are merely *delegated authentication services*. That is, they only store credentials to make authentication easier in your app, but they do not store arbitrary user data. Your Firebase is the best play for that.
- In the above example, writing to `new Firebase(.../users`) is writing to Firebase, not the authentication service, and you can write any arbitrary data of your choosing there. *However*, check the type of the birthdate that you're writing. Firebase leaf values can be of type `string`, `number`, `boolean`, or `null` - but it is likely that your datepicker might be returning an `Object` that just happens to `toString()` correctly.